# In mysql, is "explain ..." always safe?

Tags: sql, mysql, perl, dbi, explain

If I allow a group of users to submit `"explain $whatever"` to mysql (via Perl's DBI using `DBD::mysql`), is there anything that a user could put into $whatever that would make any database changes, leak non-trivial information, or even cause significant database load?  If so, how?

I know that via `"explain $whatever"` one can figure out what tables / columns exist (you have to *guess* names, though) and roughly how many records are in a table or how many records have a particular value for an indexed field.  I don't expect one to be able to get any information about the contents of unindexed fields.

`DBD::mysql` should not allow multiple statements so I don't expect it to be possible to run any query (just explain one query).  Even subqueries should not be executed, just explained.

But I'm not a mysql expert and there are surely features of mysql that I'm not even aware of.

In trying to come up with a query plan, might the optimizer actual execute an expression in order to come up with the value that an indexed field is going to be compared against?

```
explain select * from atable where class = somefunction(...)
```

where `atable.class` is indexed and not unique and `class='unused'` would find no records but `class='common'` would find a million records.  Might 'explain' evaluate `somefunction(...)`?  And then could `somefunction(...)` be written such that it modifies data?

Comment: Probably it is safe, but I wouldn't do it anyway ;) Anyone who has a reason to be fooling around with `explain` should be given a test copy of the DB and the mysql CLI. Anyone who doesn't need a test DB should be saved from writing queries, and therefore doesn't need `explain` ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Explain" can take an arbitrarily long time to execute, and use an arbitrary amount of server resources, including causing it to crash if some things are exhausted (for example, a stack overflow caused by too many nested subqueries).

"Explain" can easily exhaust temporary disc space, server address space (on 32-bit systems, virtual memory on 64-bit systems) or the thread stack (for queries constructed deliberately maliciously).

In general, you cannot allow entirely untrusted users to submit any part of any SQL at all. Even without access to a single table, they can probably still crash the server if they try hard enough.

---

EDIT: further info

A query which uses an anonymous view / materialised subquery, often executes the entire inner query upon EXPLAIN, into a temporary table.

So queries of the form

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT h1.*, h2.* FROM huge_table h1, huge_table h2) AS rediculous
```

will take forever to explain and consume the disc space in tmpdir.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  What kind of explain could take an arbitrarily long time or exhaust temporary disc space or memory?

Comment: Thanks.  That is a good insight.  It sounds like something that could be somewhat capped as simply as limiting the total size of the text after "explain ".  At least, **I** can't come up with an SQL query that grows in complexity to explain as O(n!) or even O(n**2) vs the length of query text.

Comment: Sounds like this can be used to leak data too - construct a subquery that reveals information in the form of the number of items returned.

Comment: @bdonian explain gives the approximate number of rows anyway even for "fast" explains (e.g. plain joins)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to use 'explain' to get an accurate count of rows matching precise queries.  So one could use

```
explain select * from user where name='tye' and secret like '%a%'
```

to quickly determine the letters of whatever 'secret' and then move on to determining the order of the letters, eventually revealing the value of 'secret'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to be able to connect to the database but not changing it, you should enforce that using user privileges-- if they only have SELECT privileges, they should not be able to change anything.

Comment: Thanks.  That is excellent advice.  Adding a read-only user and using that when doing "explain" completely eliminates the primary risk (people figuring out how to make updates via "explain").

Comment: The permissions system will stop people changing data, but not crashing the server or otherwise causing denial of service, see my answer.